# C++ global object initialization fails -- why? and is it possible to put objects in .DATA section?

Tags: c++, oop, embedded

I've used C on microcontrollers for quite some time now.

Recently (finally!) I managed to get GCC to compile some c++ code for my µC and started porting some code which was previously only "simulating" OOP to the real deal.

After long debugging and struggling and googling I'm left with only one problem but this one puzzles me quiet a lot. Running this code (GCC/Arm):

```
class Test {                                                                              

public:
    int val;

    Test( int val ){                                                                      
        this->val = val;                                                                  
    }
};

Test test1( 5 );                                                                          

static void _test() {

    Test test2( 7 );                                                                      

    Debug::printf( "-test1: %d-\n", test1.val );                                          
    Debug::printf( "-test2: %d-\n", test2.val );
}

int main() { _init(); /*Hardware*/ _test(); while(1){} }
```

I get as output:

```
-test1: 0-
-test2: 7-
```

So somehow `test1` doesn't get initialized as I would have expected it to be.

**Why is this so? And what is really happening here?** (And why the hell doesn't the compiler complain?)

What I would like to do: Since this is running on micro-controllers I would like to avoid using "malloc/new" but put this in .DATA sections like I would do using C:

```
struct Test {
    int val;
}

Test test1 = { 5 };
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you shouldn't be using the -> operator, it should just be a `Test.val` , not `Test->val` since your Test object instance isn't a `Test*`

Comment: Probably something is wrong with your environment's application startup , and it is not running the usual precursor code to `main()` which initializes static data and so on

Comment: @MM: Turned out this is the case. S. the comments below R Sahus answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In embedded systems programming, it is very bad practice to rely on constructor calls for objects with static storage duration.

This is because many compilers have the option to create a non-standard "minimal startup", meaning that the compiler will ignore the requirements of the C and C++ standards and **skip all initialization of static storage duration variables, including calling constructors** for such objects.

Also, in general C++ you have to be careful not to rely on order of initialization of static storage duration variables. If you have object A and B, and object A is initialized first, there must not be any code in A's constructor that relies on B to be initialized. [More info in the C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: So you're saying: Ignore this and put an `init(...)` method in?

Comment: @Scheintod Usually that is the best idea indeed. However, you'll still want constructors/destructors, for the case when you allocate objects at local scope.

Comment: Turned out in my case this isn't a compiler flag but missing linker/startup-code. See comments below R Sahu's answer. I would go with using init, but there is an itch I need to scratch because I've seen this working in Arduino / Energia IDE which both use gcc. I've highlighted the part which I think makes this the correct answer although Thomas and R Sahu was helpfull, too.

Comment: @Scheintod It is very common that such start-up code isn't present, maybe 1 out of 3 embedded projects has non-standard setups. It is a good idea to always browse through the start-up code of the project (it should be open and available to you) and see what it does. It should set up the MMU and RAM,  setup the stack (unless it's an ARM), initialize data and bss segments, and then in case of C++ run all constructors of static storage duration objects, then call main. Some of these steps may be missing.

Comment: (Well-designed embedded systems also set the watchdog, low-voltage detect etc as early as possible, preferably the very first thing done out of reset)

Answer (score 1):

Using a plain `struct` or `class` is, indeed, possible:

```
class Test { // or use struct without explicit public accessibility
public:
    int val;
};

Test  test1 = { 5 };
```

You:

- cannot do any fancy construction work using this plain layout and
- cannot have any member requiring construction.

Otherwise, you do not need worry about `new` or `malloc` if you program as you did in your example: `test2` is cheaply allocated on the stack even though a constructor is called.

Just as a side note: consider using initializer lists when you do use constructors:

```
class Test {
  int  m_val;
public:
  Test(int  val) : m_val(val) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> So somehow `test1` doesn't get initialized as I would have expected it to be.

Order of initialization is an issue that you have deal with when creating variables in global scope. One way to avoid the problem is encapsulate them with accessor functions.

The code below should work independent of order of initialization of global objects since it does not depend on a global object.

```
static Test& getTest1()
{
   static Test t(5);
   return t;
}                                                                          

static void _test() {

    Test test2( 7 );                                                                      

    Debug::printf( "-test1: %d-\n", getTest1().val );                                          
    Debug::printf( "-test2: %d-\n", test2.val );
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But I would expect global variables always be intialized before "normal" code is executed (I think everything else is pointless).

Comment: Global objects will be initialized before anything in `main` is executed.

Comment: When do you call `_test()`?

Comment: in main: int main() {

    _init(); /*Hardware*/

    _test();

    while(1){}
}

Comment: That should work. It works on my desktop and also at http://ideone.com/FAMdIC. It looks like you have a problem in your compiler/run time environment.

Comment: OK. I just wanted to ask the same question. I'm using modfied stuff from TivaWare which uses custom intialization code. So I guess it's missing something. Holy crap seems I have to deal with linker scripts and initialization code ... :(

Comment: @Scheintod unfortunately, somebody has to (or has been my experience on every embedded project I've ever worked on).   It definitely looks like the c++ run-time environment is not being initialized and global scope constructors aren't being called.   make sure you're linking in the libc++ rather than just libc.